# Android: Query sort rule for Contacts application

Tags: android, android-contacts

Is it possible to query for the sorting rule in Contacts application? I need to know what is the selected rule: "First name" or "Last name"

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, for anybody interested in this question here's the solution:

The sorting rule of Contacts application is stored in the ContactsContract.Preferences class. 
However, this class is marked with the @hide annotation. Therefore, you cannot access it.

But if you really want it - use reflection! :)

Answer (score 0):

They are sorted according to the "Display Name". Display name is auto populated with a fixed set of priority.

If a contact has only first name and no last name the display name is the first name.

If a contact has only last name and no first name the display name is the last name.

If a contact has both first and Last name then the display name is the first name space Lat name.

If none then the display name mite be the phone number or an email ID.

And in Contacts Application ***NO*** you cannot apply sorting rules.

Comment: This is not true. At least at my Motorolla Milestone. If you select Display Options context menu, in the opened dialog you can modify the "Sort List by" setting. And I'm interested in getting it's value